# how does a variable to be decided it's value without it's initialize in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Now I'm trying to digging the systemverilog as the below

```
denaliCdn_ahbTransaction burst1;

task sendTransfers;
      
burst1= new;       
burst1.Direction = DENALI_CDN_AHB_DIRECTION_WRITE;
burst1.FirstAddress = 32'h4020;//16416 M3 and M0 to S1
burst1.Kind = DENALI_CDN_AHB_BURSTKIND_INCR4;
burst1.Size = DENALI_CDN_AHB_TRANSFERSIZE_HALFWORD;
burst1.Data = new [8];

foreach (burst1.Data[ii])
burst1.Data[ii] = ii;

void'(activeMaster1.transAdd(burst1,0));
....
endtask
```

Especially, from here , how does ii be decided it's value without initialized ?

```
foreach (burst1.Data[ii])
burst1.Data[ii] = ii;
```

how does a variable to be decided it's value without it's initialize in systemverilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general answer and a specific answer to your question.

The general answer is that all types in System-Verilog initialise to specific values:

```
int    0
real   0.0
string ""
logic  1'bx
```

However, the specific answer to your question is that the code you specifically identify

```
foreach (burst1.Data[ii])
  burst1.Data[ii] = ii;
```

is actually performing initialisation rather than relying on it. The dynamic array `burst1.data` is constructed with 8 elements in the line

```
burst1.Data = new [8];
```

The line

```
foreach (burst1.Data[ii])
```

iterates over that array, looping 8 times, once for each element. The variable `ii` takes the value of the index of each element in the array, ie 0 to 7. The line

```
  burst1.Data[ii] = ii;
```

Sets element `ii` of the array to the value `ii` and so is initialising the array.

Comment: Thanks. then, does it the same as like this? for(int ii=0;ii<8;ii++) burst1.Data[ii]=ii ?

Comment: Yes, it does exactly the same in this case.