# Issue $urandom_rage having the same value in multiple systemverilog task

Tags: system-verilog

Now I'm trying to get the random values in multiple systemvalue task.
so I just implemented as the below

```
module testa;

task sendtransfer1

foreach (burst3.Data[ii1])
burst1.data[ii1] = $urandom_range (967295,0);

end task

task sendtransfer2

foreach (burst3.Data[ii2])
burst2.data[ii2] = $urandom_range (967295,0);

end task


task sendtransfer3

foreach (burst3.Data[ii3])
burst3.data[ii3] = $urandom_range (967295,0);

end task




initial begin
   for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) begin
       sendtransfer1
    end
end

initial begin
   for(int ii = 0; ii<1000; ii++) begin
       sendtransfer2
    end
end

initial begin
   for(int iii = 0; iii<1000; iii++) begin
       sendtransfer3
    end
end

endmodule
```

After I got the result, I found the three burst1,data[ii1], burst2.data[ii1] and burst3.data[ii1] output  values are the same.

I want to implement that randome values have each own random value on their task not the same value each task.

What am I supposed to do to get the each own random value in each task?

## update

```
module testa;

int ii1;
int ii2;
int ii3;

task sendtransfer1
burst1 = new;
burst1.pInst = activeMaster1;


foreach (burst3.Data[ii1])
burst1.data[ii1] = $urandom_range (967295,0);

end task

task sendtransfer2
burst2 = new;
burst2.pInst = activeMaster2;

foreach (burst3.Data[ii2])
burst2.data[ii2] = $urandom_range (967295,0);

end task


task sendtransfer3
burst3 = new;
burst3.pInst = activeMaster3;

foreach (burst3.Data[ii3])
burst3.data[ii3] = $urandom_range (967295,0);

end task




initial begin
   for( ii1 = 0; ii1<1000; ii1++) begin
       sendtransfer1
    end
end

initial begin
   for( ii2 = 0; ii2<1000; ii2++) begin
       sendtransfer2
    end
end

initial begin
   for( ii3 = 0; ii3<1000; ii3++) begin
       sendtransfer3
    end
end

endmodule
```

I'd changed as your recommend. but the random outputs values of three tasks keep the same.

and "Your best options would be to pass the value as an argument to each task." is also the same values.

[image]

Comment: why is it `foreach *burst3* ...` in all 3 loops?

Comment: @Serge foreach (burst1.Data[ii])
  burst1.Data[ii] = ii;
is actually performing initialisation rather than relying on it. The dynamic array burst1.data is constructed with 8 elements in the line

Comment: i meant that you used burst3 for every loop even though you initialized burst1, 2 and 3. I hope it is ok, but there is  no supporting evidence in the piece of code you provided.

Comment: @Serge I've got a hint from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569029/how-does-a-variable-to-be-decided-its-value-without-its-initialize-in-systemve I can't understand what piece of code do I need more for supporting?

Comment: @Serge I'm not a expert systemverilog but do I need something more even foreach (burst3.Data[ii3])
burst3.data[ii3] = $urandom_range (967295,0); to make a random values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to get your code into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem is most likely that your have local variables (i,ii,iii) declared in your three for loops, but reference ii1, ii2, ii3 inside your tasks. Your best options would be to pass the value as an argument to each task.

Comment: I'd changed as your recommend. but the random outputs values of three tasks keep the same.

Comment: Do you need 3 separate `initial` blocks? Please create an MCVE.

Comment: Yes because I want to test 3 master and 3 slave bus in the same address and random data. so i create the 3 separate initial blocks. especially I want to control each task to each master. so I made three initial block. Doesn't it possibly  work with $random system function?